# Не доступна переменная класса

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<script> 
function UserSubscribes(){ 
    this.channels = []; 
        this.GetChannels = function(){ 
            var arg = this.channels; 
            $.getJSON('/getUserChannels', function(data) { 
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('user_channels')) { 
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.user_channels.length; i++) { 
                        arg.push(data.user_channels[i].hash_channel); 
                    } 
                } 
                //console.log(arg); // Massive zapolnen

            });    
return arg; 
        }        
}

var user_subsc = new UserSubscribes(); 
var c = user_subsc.GetChannels(); 
console.log(c); // Pocemu to vivodit undefined  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про асинхронность.

```
return arg;
```

выполняется раньше чем

```
console.log(arg); // Massive zapolnen
```

Для эксперимента: перед `return arg;` добавте:

```
console.log('before return');
```

**UPD**

```
function UserSubscribes()
{ 
    this.channels = []; 
}

UserSubscribes.prototype.GetChannels = function (callback)
{
    this.channels = [];
    $.getJSON('/getUserChannels', function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('user_channels')) { 
            for (var i = 0; i < data.user_channels.length; i++) { 
                this.channels.push(data.user_channels[i].hash_channel);
            } 
        }
        if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
            callback(this.channels);
        }
    });
}

var user_subsc = new UserSubscribes(); 
user_subsc.GetChannels(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Ага - понял. А можете здесь мне объяснить и привести правильный пример. Может еще какие-то замечания будут в сторону prototype?

Comment: думаю как то так нужно делать..

Comment: Ругается на конструкцию this. = function(){}

Comment: @junart уберите строчку с этим кодом.